# mysqlDB restore to docker container from Powershell

Tags: mysql, docker, powershell

I am trying to restore database into database container but facing the below error:

Command:

```
docker exec -i "containername" mysql -u -pR --force > db.sql
```

Error log:

```
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

Comment: seems like you mistyped the command and used `<` insted of `>`

Comment: I was using > this symbol since long  it was working fine recently started facing this issue  .  "<" this is not working